# How can I insert a variable into the resulting url parameter string after submitting my GET form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-parameters

I have a form that queries a library database on another site. It works perfectly if I only include input fields for the "format" and "keyword" because the resulting parameters passed to the url come out in the correct order and the destination site recognizes it.

However, I also need my form to have an input field to select to search by "Author", "Title", "Subject" etc. This is what causes the problem. The destination site only recognizes this parameter if it is in the middle of the url (inside the keyword parameter).

**My current resulting url:**
http://alpha2.suffolk.lib.ny.us/search~S50/X?SEARCH=harry&searchscope=50&SORT=D&m=b

**What I need the url to look like:** 
http://alpha2.suffolk.lib.ny.us/search~S50/X?SEARCH=t:(harry)&searchscope=50&SORT=D&m=b

If you compare the two you will notice a couple differences. First, ignore the parentheses around harry. That doesn't make a difference. **The real issue is how do I get the "t:" to be inserted into my url?** The "t:" comes from selecting "Title" as the thing to search by.

Here is my current form HTML (If you remove the "searchtype" select box at the bottom the form will execute without errors, but I need it to execute with it.)

```
<form class="form-inline" role="search" method="get" name="searchform" id="searchform" action="http://alpha2.suffolk.lib.ny.us/search~S50/X">
                  <div class="form-group" style="float: left; margin-top: 6px;">
                    <label class="form-title">Search Collection</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="SEARCH" id="SEARCH" placeholder="Enter Search Terms..." />
                    <input type="hidden" value="50" name="searchscope" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="D" name="SORT" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                    <label for="searchformat">For:</label>
                    <select name="m" id="m">
                            <option value="">ANY</option>
                            <option value="a">BOOK</option>
                            <option value="e">EBOOK DOWNLOAD</option>
                            <option value="l">LARGE PRINT BOOK</option>
                            <option value="b">BLU-RAY</option>
                            <option value="g">DVD</option>
                            <option value="i">AUDIO BOOK CD</option>
                            <option value="h">AUDIO BOOK MP3CD</option>
                            <option value="x">EAUDIOBOOK DOWNLOAD</option>
                            <option value="q">PLAYAWAY</option>
                            <option value="j">MUSIC CD</option>
                            <option value="p">MAGAZINE/NEWSPAPER</option>
                            <option value="n">EMAGAZINE DOWNLOADS</option>
                            <option value="v">PLAYAWAY VIEW</option>
                            <option value="s">VIDEO GAME</option>
                            <option value="r">CD-ROM</option>
                            <option value="d">VHS</option>
                            <option value="t">GAMES/PUZZLES</option>
                            <option value="f">DIGITAL IMAGE</option>
                            <option value="z">EVIDEO DOWNLOADS</option>
                            <option value="y">EMUSIC DOWNLOADS</option>
                            <option value="c">SHEET MUSIC</option>
                            <option value="m">MAP</option>
                            <option value="w">ONLINE RESOURCE</option>
                            <option value="o">OTHER MATERIALS</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                    <label for="searchtype">By:</label>
                    <select name="" id="searchtype">
                            <option value="a:"> Author</option>
                            <option value="t:"> Title</option>
                            <option value="d:"> Subject</option>
                            <option value="N:"> Note</option>
                            <option value="" selected="selected"> Keyword</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchsubmit" type="Submit">GO</button>
                </form>
```

**EDIT:**

The attempted Javascript (as requested in the comments):

```
<script>
function searchSubmit() {
    m = document.getElementById("m").value;
    t = document.getElementById("searchtype").value;
    a = document.getElementById("searcharg").value;
    var newurl = "alpha2.suffolk.lib.ny.us/search/X~S22?SEARCH="; + t + a + "&searchscope=50&SORT=D&m=" + m;
    var searchform = document.getElementById("searchform");
    searchform.action = newurl; searchform.submit();
} 
</script>
```

Comment: You tagged your question with the javascript tag, so I cam assuming that you are looking for a javascript solution, yet you aren't showing any of your current javascript to try to modify the `SEARCH` field value to prepend `a:/t:/d:/N:`.  Can you show what you have so far and explain what is not working?

Comment: Have you considered an AJAX approach? It'll be easier to manage query params that way. On form submit you could just `e.preventDefault()` on the event, set up the query exactly as you need it, then fire off the request.

Comment: I tagged javascript because I feel like a solution may come from there. I did try this function to no avail: 
`<script>
function searchSubmit() {
 m = document.getElementById("m").value;
       t = document.getElementById("searchtype").value;
 a = document.getElementById("searcharg").value;
     
 var newurl = "http://alpha2.suffolk.lib.ny.us/search/X~S22?SEARCH=" + t + a + "&searchscope=50&SORT=D&m=" + m;
       var searchform = document.getElementById("searchform");
 searchform.action = newurl;
 searchform.submit();
}
</script>`

Comment: Thanks @Prefix could you provide an example of how that looks/works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is get the searchtype-value and add it to the input-search before submitting. Here is a [JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v95t35ct/) example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchform").on("submit", function(e){
        var keyWord = $("#SEARCH").val();
        var searchtype = $("#searchtype").val();
        $("#SEARCH").val(searchtype + keyWord);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the JavaScript approach, you will have to use AJAX and prevent the default behavior of the button.

```
document.getElementById("searchsubmit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //here you set up your variables. One example is 
  var mysearch = "SEARCH=" + document.getElementById("searchtype").value + document.getElementById("SEARCH").value;
  xhttp.open("GET", "yourURL?" + yourVariables, true);
  xhttp.send();
});
```